# How To push Docker Image to Isolated Remote Registry Using Docker Desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry

I Have a Docker Registry running on Linux machine on AWS Isolated Environment that needs a Palo Alto VPN Connection to establish connection to that machine.

I am trying to use the Docker desktop as I have installed the VPN Client on my Windows machine.so that I can establish connection to my AWS Machine that running docker registry.

1. installed Docker Desktop on my Windows Machine
2. Established the VPN Connection to my VPC on AWS
3. Established the SSH Tunnel

> ssh -L 2375:localhost:2375 your-username@your-remote-host -i
> /path/to/your-private-key

when i try to push the image Using

> docker push localhost:5000/your-image-name

it is says

> the docker push Error response from daemon: Client sent an HTTP
> request to an HTTPS server.

,

how can I achieve this using Windows Machine as I said the connection to the remote docker registry requires VPN Connection.